# Hot to apply particular properties file to an application run by spring-boot-maven-plugin?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin, spring-profiles

There is a properties file `application-special.yml` that I use for launching app locally with `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. When the file is located in `main/resources` it is enough to pass `special` as profile name to the command:

```
clean spring-boot:run -D spring-boot.run.profiles=special
```

**How to apply this property file when it is located outside the project?**

Comment: You can provide external property files to spring boot application like this -mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--spring.config.additional-location=file:/directory_path/filename.yml"

Comment: @AbhinavJain please post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide any number of external property files with spring-boot like this:

> mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--spring.config.additional-location=file:/directory_path/filename.yml,file:/directory_path/filename2.yml"